# Order when floating elements seems to be reversed

Tags: jquery, css, layout, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am trying to work with the layout of my web application. It's not going that well...

You can see my example here at Fiddle: [code](http://jsfiddle.net/2DdFJ/1/)

As you can see the elements appears in the reverse order compared to the divs in the html-code.

I don't have control over the content of the wrapping "top"-class, it is generated by a third party plug-in (DataTables). Hence, I can not add any "< br />"-tag. However, I can work with the classes in my css-file, the most (if not all) elements have some class.

I would like the order of the elements to be presented in a "correct" order and the drop-down box on a new line. The three buttons should still be on the right side though.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/2DdFJ/13/

Float right causes your first element in the same level to go right, then second element to the left of the rightmost etc, which was why you have a reversed elements

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want the three buttons to appear on the right side.

Comment: Thanks, it's correct. Same answer as @Didier Ghys (unfortunately, can only chose one answer..).

Comment: You can smile again, you did provide a different solution which works, there were some problems with @Didier's solution. Thanks Nifty.

Answer (score 2):

Floating element to right puts them in reversed order.

You'd have to either put them in different order in the markup, so floating right will show them in correct order.

Or you can apply `text-align: right` to the container, and only `float: left` the element to appear on left side.

```
.top { text-align: right; }

.DTTT_container, .ColVis { display: inline-block }

.dataTables_length { float: left; }
```

​
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/2nPVZ/)

Comment: Actually, I wasn't getting the drop-down-box on a new line with this solution. It turns out that @NiftyDude had the solution. Check out his example.

Comment: I missed the part of the newline indeed. By the way, simply removing float on `#mytickettable_length` and apply `text-align: left` results in what you're after. I have updated the fiddle.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Didier! In my post I skipped that I want several elements on the second row, thought that would be easy to fix after solving the problem in my post (mistake...). I know this post is already answered, but how can I get several elements in a row on the second row. Updated your example: [http://jsfiddle.net/2nPVZ/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/2nPVZ/4/) . I have severe issues grasping the logic behind positioning...